# In Ubuntu Linux, how do I list packages installed from the “universe” repository?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, dpkg

On an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server, I want to list installed packages and see what repository they come from.

It’s easy to list installed packages, but it does not include the name of the repository (such as “main” or “universe”). And this information isn’t in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, so `dpkg-query` doesn’t show it either.

I want to get a list of “unsupported” software—that is, software that doesn’t come from the “main” repository, and for which Ubuntu does not guarantee security updates.

Note: This is a server. It does not have X, GNOME or KDE installed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay, I figured out how to do this:

```
aptitude search "~i" -F "%s# %p"
```

Which of course can easily be grepped to find items from the “universe” repository:

```
aptitude search "~i" -F "%s# %p" | grep universe
```

Comment: +1. I was getting there, but I am surprised this isn't better documented either in Ubuntu documentation or Debian's website. It is something I do all the time in Synaptic, but I have never yet needed it from CLI.

Comment: `aptitude search -F "%s# %p" "~i ?section(universe)"`

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a custom format for the output of the dpkg command (using the -f option). Try something like this, using the Origin variable:

```
dpkg-query -f='${Package} ${Version}\t${Origin}\n' --get-selections
```

There's more info on the formatting argument on this page:
http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=dpkg-query

> The  default format string is
>   "${Package}\t${Version}\n".  Actu-
>   ally, all other fields found  in  the 
>   status  file  (i.e.  user defined 
>   fields) can be requested, too. They
>   will be printed as- is, though, no
>   conversion nor error checking is  done
>   on  them. To  get  the  name of the
>   dpkg maintainer and the installed ver-
>   sion, you could run:
>
> dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}
>   ${Version}\t${Maintainer}\n' dpkg

Comment: Unfortunately neither `${Origin}` nor `${Source}` give any output. Example query: `dpkg-query -W -f='${Package} ${Version}\t${Origin}\n' 'apache2*'`. If `dpkg-query` is getting its data from  `/var/lib/dpkg/status` then it won’t have the information because that file does not identify the origin repository.

Comment: This does not work. `--get-selections` is not a valid argument to `dpkg-query`.

Comment: `--show` is the correct command (not `--get-selections`), but, as @Nate pointed out, there's no field available that contains the desired information.

Answer (score 1):

I tried 
    aptitude search ~i -F "%s# %p"

in ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 but it didn't show repositories.

So I wrote this small script:

```
# more origins.sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(dpkg -l |grep ^ii |awk -F' ' '{print $2}'); do
  apt-cache showpkg "$i"|head -3|grep -v '^Versions'|cut -d'(' -f2|cut -d')' -f1|sed -e 's/^Package: //;' | paste -d '\t' - -
done
```

Then

```
bash origins.sh|grep universe
```

Comment: The version extracted from `showpkg` output isn't necessarily the installed version, so this might work for you, but if a package is available from more than one repository in `sources.list` (say, if you have backports enabled), it will not show you from which repository the package has been installed.

Comment: this is really cool. Actually it is really helpful and important because universe is not updated 5 years in LTS unlike main :( More info: http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/ubuntu-lts-many-vulnerabilities-despite-long-term-support.385386/

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer but might be used to help.  A colleague showed me this the other day.  You can find out where a package is from using this command:

`apt-cache policy <package-name>`

For example:

```
 apt-cache policy xterm  
 xterm:  
 Installed: 271-1ubuntu2.1    
 Candidate: 271-1ubuntu2.1  
 Version table:    *** 271-1ubuntu2.1 0  
         500 http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages  
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status  
      271-1ubuntu2 0  
         500 http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```